# Extract Image Dimensions from Base64 String

Tags: php, regex, image, base64

Is there a relatively simple way (perhaps regular expressions?) of detecting the dimensions -height & width - of an image from a base64 string (and perhaps the filesize)? That is to say without actually creating an image resource?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Decode the base64, and use `getimagesizefromstring()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php

This will be way more reliable than trying to write your own handling of each image type available.

Comment: getimagesizefromstring is a PHP5.4 function. What about php5.3?